# How to construct and write a byte to a binary file in PHP

Tags: php, binary, byte, bit, fwrite

I'm trying to write a byte in binary to a file.

I have the binary byte (8 bits) as a string, e.g. `"01100101"`

How do I write this as one byte in PHP?  When I `fopen` with `"wb"` it still writes it in ASCII and puts `01100101` in a file.  I might be confused how how the whole process works..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write binary file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11341506/608639)

Answer (score 3):

I think [`pack()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) is what you're looking for.

```
function bin2bstr($input)
// Convert a binary expression (e.g., "100111") into a binary-string
{
    if (!is_string($input)) return null; // Sanity check

    // Pack into a string
    return pack('H*', base_convert($input, 2, 16));
}
```

Comment: Just commenting here to help me find this later. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$number = bindec("01100101");

$number = 0b01100101; // better
```

The notation 0b... is for binary numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_put_contents('aa',pack('ifA5',1001,25.5,'asdfg'));
var_dump(unpack('iint/ffloat/A5lkl',file_get_contents('aa')));
```