# Write binary file in PHP

Tags: php, file-io, io, binaryfiles

I have wrote a PHP file which will save a JPEG file in the server and part of the code is listed as follow:

```
    //create folder if folder not exist
if (!is_dir($save_path)){

    $old = umask(0);
    $flag = @mkdir($save_path,0777);
    umask($old); 

if(isset($flag)){
    $string = 'Folder Create Success!'."\n";
}else{
    $string= 'Folder Create Fail!'."\n";
}
echo $string;

}else{

   echo "Folder exist!!!!";

}


//write the content to the server
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];
$binary=base64_decode($base);
header('Content-Type: image/jpg; charset=utf-8');

if(!$file = fopen($path, 'wb')){

    echo 'Image upload Fail!'."\n";
    return;
}
else
{

    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);

}
```

The problem is when I run the code, if the folder does not exist, it create the folder only but the content can't save in the folder. The error message is :

[Thu Jul 05 16:59:06 2012] [error] [client 10.95.61.220] PHP Warning:  fopen(/mnt/csis/upload/newphoto/others/12346_test/12346_test_2012-07-05_others_abc.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/upload_image.php on line 57

However, if I run the code again, since the folder was created in the past, it work properly. The content can save in the folder......

Anything I get wrong? I try to find the answer on the web but still can't solve the problem.

Anyone can help, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try changing the creation of the folder to use the [recursive flag](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php):

```
$flag = @mkdir($save_path . "/" . $file,0777,true);
```

Comment: are you sure ? I see that you have both `$path` and `$basepath` -  can you `echo` them and show me ?

Comment: if it still doesn't work, try to use `chdir($path);` before you open the file.

Comment: actually, the $path is the path of the file to be saved and $savepath is the path + file name. On the other hand, I have tried chdir($path) before open the file but the problem still exist...

Comment: but you're trying to do: `fopen($path, 'wb')` which means, according to your last remark, to open the directory...

Comment: eventually I have solved the problem by wait 10 second to save the content when a new folder created.....

Comment: @user1411475 were you running this logic in a loop ?