# PHP : write binary string to file

Tags: php, file, binary, fwrite

I had encoded image to binary ($binaryImage) in a string. Now I want to save it in file in server.Here is the code, but I got the result:
fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given... .
Is the code wrong?

```
            $binary=base64_decode($binaryImage);
            header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');

            $file = fopen('../uploadedImages/'.$filename, 'wb');
            // Create File
            fwrite($file, $binary);
            fclose($file);
```

(EDIT) I also tried :

```
            if($file===false){
                echo "Failed to file";
            }            
            // Create File
            if(fwrite($file, $binary)===false){
                echo "Failed to write";
            }
```

get this message:

```
fopen(../uploadedImages/FB_IMG_1437004428570.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/u505221043/public_html/welcom/include/db_functions.php
```

My php code is in "include" directory. And "uploadedImage" is 777 mode.

```
->include
   ->function.php
->uploadedImages
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with writing the string. The issue simply is that your `fopen()` fails and returns `false` instead of a resource handler. Since you do not do any error checking or handling at all in your code you try to use a file handler with value `false` which won't work and leads to the error message. As always: _read the documentation of the functions you use if you encounter issues!_

Comment: call getcwd to check whether you are really in the include folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write binary file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11341506/608639)

Answer (score 1):

[`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) returns a boolean when it fails to open a file.

This could be for several reasons such as an incorrect path or permissions.

I recommend adding a guard clause, at least to debug this issues:

```
$file = fopen('../uploadedImages/' . $filename, 'wb');
if ($file === false) {
    exit("Failed to file");
}
```

Comment: He has to check for permissions also : 'ls -la' in the image's directory and 'chown -R www-data .' if php doesn't have the execution and reading permission

Comment: @Answers_Seeker and this is true for all the folders in the path: the http servers process requires permission to enter those. Oh, and the use is not necessarily `www-data`. Also changing the owner is not the only option for this. Often it is much more elegant to change group writing access.

Comment: @akascha: It adds the owner it doesn't change it. You are right about www-data but it's the standard